# Can I sacrifice and regenerate Augur of Skulls multiple times in the same turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Augur of Skulls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=augur%20of%20skulls) has

> {1}{B}: Regenerate Augur of Skulls.

and

> Sacrifice Augur of Skulls: Target player discards two cards. Activate this ability only during your upkeep.

Can I sacrifice and regenerate Augur of Skulls multiple times in the same turn as long as I have the mana open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No, that won't work**

Regeneration prevents the destruction of a permanent, but sacrificing a permanent is different from destroying it:

> 701.16. Sacrifice
>
> 701.16a To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control. **Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.**

Comment: In short, Regeneration does not fix a Sacrifice.  If you Sacrifice a Permanent as a **Cost** (Left hand of the colon, it goes to the graveyard.  **Nothing** can prevent this from happening, because it is a cost.

Comment: @Nelson It has nothing to do with being a cost or an effect. If the cost was "destroy a creature you control", regeneration would save the creature. If "sacrifice a creature" was the effect, regeneration still wouldn't save it.

Comment: Sacrifice as an effect can be prevented, or redirected, or replaced.  I'm not really alluding that regeneration can save a sacrifice, but a sacrifice as an effect isn't nearly as final as sacrifice as a cost.  The bottom line is, in **no situation**, will you be able to save a creature from Sacrifice as a Cost.  You can save a creature from sacrifice as an effect, but not through regeneration.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that, because Regeneration doesn't protect against a Sacrifice.

The rules for Sacrifice even explicitly assert as much:

> **701.15a** To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control. **Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.**

For clarity, [Regenerate in an ability means](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Regenerate) "The next time [permanent] would be destroyed this turn, instead remove all damage marked on it and tap it. If it’s an attacking or blocking creature, remove it from combat."